# Proving that if two linear transformations are one-to-one and onto, then their composition is also.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, function-and-relation-composition

I am attempting to solve a problem with the following given conditions:

Let V, W. and Z be vector spaces, and let $T:V \longrightarrow W$ and $U: W\longrightarrow Z$ be linear.Prove that if U and T are one-to-one and onto, then UT is also.

Here is my attempt for the one-to-one part:

"Suppose that U and T are one-to-one and onto. By assumption, for $\forall  \space T(x),T(y) \in W $ where T(x) = T(y), we have x = y. It also follows by assumption that $ \forall  \space U(g),U(h) \in Z $, we have g = h. Now suppose g = T(x) and h = T(y). Then we have UT(x) = U(T(x)) = U(g) = U(h) = U(T(y)) = UT(y).

Thus we conclude UT is one-to-one."

Is this a valid proof?

Thanks!

Comment: No. You need to show (i) if $(UT)x = (UT)y$ then $x = y$ and (ii) for all $z \in Z$ that there exists some $v \in V$ such that $(UT)v = z$.

Comment: You are saying it the other way round. You must assume $UT(x)=UT(y)$, under that assumption you have $U(T(x))=U(T(y))$, which implies $T(x)=T(y)$ because of the injectivity of $U$ and that implies $x=y$ because of the injectivity of $T$, and that means $ UT$ is injective. Tge proof for the surjectivity is similar

Comment: It is true for any bijections $f:V\to W$ and $g:W\to Z$ for any sets $V,W,Z.$

Comment: @Eliana Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}&UTv=UTv'\stackrel{U\,\text{is}\,1-1}\implies Tv=Tv'\stackrel{V\,\text{is}\,1-1}\implies v=v'\;,\;\;\text{so}\,\,UT\;\text{is}\;1-1\\{}\\
(i)\;&\forall\,z\in Z\;\exists\,w\in W\;\text{with}\;Uw=z\;\;\text{because surjectivity of}\;U\;,\;\;\text{and}\\
(ii)\;&\exists\,v\in V\;\text{with}\;Tv=w\;,\;\;\text{because surjectivity of}\;T\\
&\text{and from (i)-(ii) it follows}\;\;UTv=Uw=z\implies UT\;\text{is surjective}\end{align*}$$

The above is true for general functions and sets, not necessarily for linear maps and linear spaces.

Comment: @KingTut Any time. It was a pleasure.