# Let $S:U\rightarrow V, \ T:V\rightarrow W$ and if $S$ and $T$ are both injective/surjective, is $T\circ S$ injective/surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For injective side, in my opinion, we can find two square matrices $A, B$ with each injective but $AB$ has a zero row ($\dim\ker(AB)\ne 0$), so $TS$ is not injective. But I don't know how to find such matrices.

For surjective side, I have no idea how to start.

I feel my idea is very confusing, could someone give me a clear way to solve the problem?

Comment: This was already asked a few days ago, check [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673982/proving-that-if-two-linear-transformations-are-one-to-one-and-onto-then-their-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are actually true.

For injectivity, we have to prove that $TS(u)=TS(u')$ implies $u=u'$ for all $u,u'\in U$. Now if $T$ is injective,
$$TS(u)=TS(u')\Rightarrow S(u)=S(u'),$$and if $S$ is injective as well,
$$S(u)=S(u')\Rightarrow u=u'.$$

For surjectivity, we need to show that for all $w\in W$, it is possible to find $u\in U$ such that $TS(u)=w$. If $T$ is surjective, then there must be $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=w$; and if $S$ is surjective as well, then there must exist $u\in U$ such that $S(u)=v$. We then have
$$TS(u)=T(S(u))=T(v)=w.$$

Notice that I never supposed here that $T,S$ were linear or even that $U,V,W$ were vector spaces; this is actually true for any functions between sets.

Comment: Is it possible that $TS$ is bijective yet neither $S$ nor $T$ is bijective?

Comment: Yes, although you would still have that $S$ would be injective and $T$ surjective. Consider for example $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $S:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2:x\mapsto (x,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to show that for any $w\in W$ there is $u \in U$ such that $TS(u) =w$.

Let $w \in W$ be any vector. Since $T$ is surjective, there is $v \in V$ such that $T(v)=w$. Now, since $S$ is surjective, there is $u \in U$ such that $S(u) = v$. It follows that

$$ TS(u)=T(S(u))=T(v)=w$$

so $TS$ is surjective.

Injectivity is similar.