# How to prove that if $S: U\rightarrow V$ and $T: V\rightarrow W$ are surjective, then $TS$ is also surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I feel my order has problem:

for $u\in U, v \in V, w\in W $. Since $S$ is surjective, we have $S(u)=v$. Since $T$ is surjective we have $T(S(u))=T(v)=w$. Therefore we have TS surjective.

Comment: You already asked the same question and accepted an answer here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678647/let-su-rightarrow-v-tv-rightarrow-w-and-if-s-and-t-are-both-injective/1678668#1678668 Maybe you should be more specific about what your problem is, otherwise you will just get the same kind of answers again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start from $w\in W$ and express it as $w=TS(u)$, for some $u\in U$.

By assumption, $T$ is surjective, so there is $v\in V$ with $T(v)=w$. Again, by assumption, there is $u\in U$ with $S(u)=v$. Then
$$
TS(u)=T(S(u))=T(v)=w
$$
as required.