# If $U$ and $T$ are one to one and onto then $UT$ is also - why is my proof not sound?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$, $W$, and $Z$ be vector spaces, and let $T: V \to W$ and $U: W \to Z$ be linear. Prove that if $U$ and $T$ are one to one and onto then $UT$ is also.

I've seen other solutions to this problem such as this one: [Proving that if two linear transformations are one-to-one and onto, then their composition is also.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673982/proving-that-if-two-linear-transformations-are-one-to-one-and-onto-then-their-c)  and they all approach it in the same fashion. What I want to know is why is my approach not correct:

**Attempt:**

One-to-one:

Since $U$ and $T$ are both one-to-one, this means $N(T) = \{0\}$ and $N(U) = \{0\}$. Therefore:

$$T(0) = 0 \\ U(T(0)) = U(0) \\ UT(0) = 0 \\ \Rightarrow N(UT) = \{0\}$$

Onto:

$$T(V) = W \\ U(T(V)) = U(W) \\ UT(V) = Z $$

Therefore $UT$ is onto.

Comment: The equality $UT(0)=0$ would be true even if the null space of $UT$ contains more than just $0.$ So you can't conclude that the null space contains only $0$ based just on that. You need to show that nothing other than $0$ is in the null space.

Comment: How would that be the case if T and U individually are already one to one? Is there something more refined about a composition I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not saying there are cases in which that happens; rather I am saying that in order to _prove_ that it doesn't happen, you need to prove more than just $UT(0)=0.$ You need to prove that there is no value of $x\ne0$ for which $UT(x)=0. \qquad$

Comment: I see. Besides just doing questions do yo know of other ways I could sharpen my reasoning skills? Because it seems that any time I'm working on a problem I'm not capturing the whole picture in my proofs....As you've probably seen in other questions of mine you've helped out on. Gets frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $ 0_V \in \ker (UT) $ as you showed. To complete the proof of $ \ker (UT) $ only consists of $ 0_V $, we will show that for any $ v \in \ker (UT) $ we have that $ v = 0_V $. So, take $ v \in \ker (UT) $ and note that this means  $ T (v) \in \ker (U) $. Therefore, since $ U $ is one-to-one, $ T (v) = 0_W $, which in turn means that $ v \in \ker (T) $, and then $ v = 0_V $ because $ T $ is one-to-one. This completes the proof.